# Apache POI Excel - get user who opened the current file

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

Excel performs "safe save" - when you open "`<name>.xlsx`" it saves the file "`~$<name>.xlsx`" and performs a delete/rename when closing Excel. When another user opens the same Excel file, Excel shows a message that "User X has already opened the file", so I assume that the current user ist stored in "`~$<name>.xlsx`".

Now the question: is it possible to read this user from "`~$<name>.xlsx`" with Apache POI?

UPDATE:
I learned that it depends on the share / directory of the Excel file and the underlying file system. In my case it was a MacOS share and even Excel was not able to display the user. Otherwise I am sure that Axel Richter is right and his comment is the answer to this question.

Comment: No need for `apache poi`. Simply check the bytes of that `~$<name>.xlsx` file. You will see the user name `ANSI` encoded as well as `UTF-16LE` encoded.

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot access `~$<name>.xlsx`, because Excel locks the file. I receive "process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process". On the other hand, how does Excel solves this? Excel is able to display the user name on different computers so it can deal with the lock.